# C# generics casting issue

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic Filter class, and I want to make a conditional version of this class:

```
public abstract class Filter<T, R> 
{
    protected abstract R GetResult(T input);

    private class JoinedFilterIf<S> : Filter<T, S>
    {
        private readonly Filter<T, R> _left;
        private readonly Filter<R, S> _right;
        private readonly Func<R, bool> _condition;

        public JoinedFilterIf(Filter<T, R> left, Filter<R, S> right, Func<R, bool> condition)
        {
            _left = left;
            _right = right;
            _condition = condition;
        }

        protected override S GetResult(T input)
        {
            var result = _left.GetResult(input);
            return _condition(result) ? _right.GetResult(result) : (S)((object)result);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to avoid boxing in the GetResult return expression?

Comment: Does this code compile ? There's no definition of the R, or is there ?

Comment: There's also no definition for the `T`.  All your generic types have to be defined on the class.

Comment: You would probably be able to avoid the casting if you can set up some `where` clauses in your generic definition of your class.

Comment: @Marty Sorry, I updated the code, now it should work

Comment: So when the condition is true you use a filter to turn the `R` into an `S`, but if it is false you know the `R` is an `S`?

Comment: Surely this can only work if `left` has type `Filter<T, S>`?

Comment: @juharr Sorry, I updated the code

Comment: Sorry Voo, Your code doesn't even compile.. maybe just following what the compiler has to say would help ?

Comment: Would it make any sense to have `left` be `Filter<T, S>` and `right` be `Filter<S, S>`?

Comment: what is the return type of `GetResult` for Filler ?

Comment: I need to have the result S in both cases. But if the condition is true then right should be executed and it should return S, otherwise right should not be executed and left should return S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to compile..

What I've added is a `where S: R`
If that's what You were looking for

```
 public abstract class Filter<T, R>
    {
        protected abstract R GetResult(T input);

        private class JoinedFilterIf<S> : Filter<T, S> where S : R
        {
            private readonly Filter<T, R> _left;
            private readonly Filter<R, S> _right;
            private readonly Func<R, bool> _condition;

            public JoinedFilterIf(Filter<T, R> left, Filter<R, S> right, Func<R, bool> condition)
            {
                _left = left;
                _right = right;
                _condition = condition;
            }

            protected override S GetResult(T input)
            {
                var result = _left.GetResult(input);
                return _condition(result) ? _right.GetResult(result) : (S)(result);
            }
        }
    }
```

Basically what this means - is that it's required that 'S' will be inherited from 'R'

Comment: You should probably combine two answers in a single one

Answer (score 0):

The question for me - is why are You introducing an additional type S ? 
I believe that in both cases having only 'T' and 'R' defined should be enough.. and the it would look like this

```
public abstract class Filter<T, R> where R : T
{
    protected abstract R GetResult(T input);

    private class JoinedFilterIf<S> : Filter<T, R> 
    {
        private readonly Filter<T, R> _left;
        private readonly Filter<T, R> _right;
        private readonly Func<R, bool> _condition;

        public JoinedFilterIf(Filter<T, R> left, Filter<T, R> right, Func<R, bool> condition)
        {
            _left = left;
            _right = right;
            _condition = condition;
        }

        protected override R GetResult(T input)
        {
            var result = _left.GetResult(input);
            return _condition(result) ? _right.GetResult(result) : (result);
        }
    }
}
```

What this is saying - is that the result R will be a derived type from T, so it could be passed back into the 'GetResult' function as if it was of type T

Comment: The filter has T input and R output. The joint filter has R intermediate result. I can't make R:T in base class because I can have other implementations, where T and R don't have any relations

Comment: But possibly the first solution will suit me